# How to use Glyphicons when exporting react-bootstrap

Tags: fonts, webpack, webpack-dev-server, glyphicons, react-bootstrap

I have 2 projects: **Project1** and **Project2**.

**Project1** uses **react-bootstrap**. **Project1** uses all the components of react-bootstrap and create a wrapper over react-bootstrap components(Don't ask why, it is a requirement). **Project2** is supposed to use **Project1** (when exported) as a wrapper library for react-bootstrap.

**Project1** -->

*index.js:*

```
import { Bootstrap } from 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
...
import Glyphicon from './src/components/Glyphicon';
...
export default {
...
Glyphicon,
...
};
```

*src/components/Glyphicon.jsx:*

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { RBGlyphicon } from 'react-bootstrap';

const Glyphicon = props => (
  <RBGlyphicon
    id={props.id}
    bsClass={props.clClass}
    glyph={props.glyph}
  />
);

Glyphicon.defaultProps = {
  id: undefined,
  clClass: 'glyphicon',
  glyph: undefined,
};

Glyphicon.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string,
  clClass: PropTypes.string,
  glyph: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default Glyphicon;
```

*webpack.config.js:*

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

    module.exports = (env = {}) => {
      const isProduction = env.production === true;
      return {
        entry: './index.js',
        output: {
          path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
          filename: 'Project1.js',
          libraryTarget: 'umd',
          library: 'Project1',
        },
        module: {
          rules: [
            {
              test: /.(js|jsx)?$/,
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
              test: /\.css$/,
              loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
            },
            {
              test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
              loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff',
            },
            {
              test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
              loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream',
            },
            {
              test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
              loader: 'file-loader',
            },
            {
              test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
              loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml',
            },
          ],
        },
        resolve: {
          extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
        },
        plugins: [
          new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
          }),
          new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
        ],
      };
    };
```

> I export this **Project1** as a bundle called Project1 using **webpack** and copy it in **Project2** in *src* folder. I don't copy the font files generated in this build

Now the problem starts with [Glyphicons](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#glyphicons).

**Project2**-->

*src/App.jsx:*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Project1 from './Project1';
...
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
...
<Project1.Glyphicon glyph="camera" />Camera
...
</div>
);
}
}
export default App;
```

*index.js:*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './src/App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

*index.html:*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root">
    </div>
    <script src='/bundle.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I use *webpack-dev-server* to build **Project2** and run in the browser. When I use *Glyphicon.jsx* in **Project2**, the icons don't show up in browser. Here is the errors which show up in Chrome Browser console:

[Chrome Browser Debug Console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGlAn.png)

Now I am aware that the problem is related to fonts.

> Even if I copy these generated font files and paste in root of **Project2**, I still get same errors.

What should I do to export these font files from **Project1** so that they can be used in **Project2**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 is not supporting the glyph icons, either user bootstrap 3 or use font awesome.

[bootstrap doc](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#components)

Comment: Yes, this is what I figured after lots of trials and finally gave up on using glyph icons as I need Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 3):

Without going too deep into the details of your project. I'll walk you on how to get Bootstrap Glypicons to show on your React app.

1- Install package

```
npm install react-bootstrap --save-dev
```

2- In the desired file where you want your glyphicon:

```
import Glyphicon from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Glyphicon'
```

3- Now write, here I use 'search' icon as an example:

```
 <span>
    <Glyphicon glyph="search"/>
 </span>
```

4- when you inspect your html, this will/should be the compiled output:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
```

5- Finally. THIS is what made my icons to actually display on the browser:

```
   In your css file apply the CDN:
   /* Glyphicons*/
 @import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

Naturally, I assume you already have bootstrap wired to the rest of your project. I'm addressing only the Glyphicon matter.
So after you're done, kill and restart your webpack to see the changes reflected.